# Why is my Ruby script utilizing 90% of my CPU?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, logging, daemon

I wrote a admin script that tails a heroku log and every n seconds, it summarizes averages and notifies me if i cross a certain threshold (yes I know and love new relic -- but I want to do custom stuff).

Here is the [entire script](https://gist.github.com/3063475).

I have never been a master of IO and threads, I wonder if I am making a silly mistake.  I have a couple of daemon threads that have `while(true){}` which could be the culprit.  For example:

```
# read new lines
f = File.open(file, "r")
f.seek(0, IO::SEEK_END)
while true do
  select([f])
  line = f.gets
  parse_heroku_line(line)
end
```

I use one daemon to watch for new lines of a log, and the other to periodically summarize.

Does someone see a way to make it less processor-intensive?

Comment: That `while true do` runs continuously and forever, without pause. That's not great.

Comment: Addd `sleep 1` at the end of the loop so it doesn't bog down the cpu.

Comment: @TheZ looping forever is rather his desire. The problem is failing to block on read because select considers EOF ready for read.

Comment: @dbenhur Looping forever is not the issue I was addressing, it was in conjunction with the "without pause" part that worries me. There is no way to exit that loop and it runs without any kind of respite for the cpu.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This probably runs hot because you never really block while reading from the temporary file. [`IO::select`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html#method-c-select) is a thin layer over POSIX [select(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select). It looks like you're trying to block until the file is ready for reading, but select(2) considers EOF to be ready ("a file descriptor is also ready on end-of-file"), so you always return right away from select then call gets which returns nil at EOF.

You can get a truer EOF reading and nice blocking behavior by avoiding the thread which writes to the temp file and instead using [`IO::popen`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html#method-c-popen) to fork the `%x[heroku logs --ps router --tail --app pipewave-cedar]` log tailer, connected to a ruby IO object on which you can loop over `gets`, exiting when `gets` returns `nil` (indicating the log tailer finished). `gets` on the pipe from the tailer will block when there's nothing to read and your script will only run as hot as it takes to do your line parsing and reporting.

EDIT: I'm not set up to actually try your code, but you should be able to replace the log tailer thread and your temp file read loop with this code to get the behavior described above:

```
IO.popen( %w{ heroku logs --ps router --tail --app my-heroku-app } ) do |logf|
  while line = logf.gets
    parse_heroku_line(line) if line =~ /^/
  end
end
```

I also notice your reporting thread does not do anything to synchronize access to `@total_lines`, `@total_errors`, etc. So, you have some minor race conditions where you can get inconsistent values from the instance vars that `parse_heroku_line` method updates.

Comment: That's the trick. Consuming input via a piped stream is way better than spinning and reading relentlessly.

Comment: @dbenhur -- strugling with the popen syntax. Would be awesome if you could update your answer with a block of code showing the new daemon loop -- or update the gist.

Comment: @Jonathan I added a code snippet that _should_ do the trick, but I haven't actually tried it anywhere :)

Comment: Awesome!  That did the trick.  The other thing i had to do was wrap that in a thread and join it with the summerizer thread.  Updated gist: https://gist.github.com/3063475


So good!  Wish I could give you more points than a check and a up-vote.

Comment: @Jonathan glad it worked for you.  You should still wrap all the lines that touch the totaling instance vars with a [`Mutex#synchronize`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Mutex.html#method-i-synchronize) block.

Comment: @dbenhur -- done,  gist updated: https://gist.github.com/3063475.  Ahhh that feels much better.

Answer (score 1):

`select` is about whether a read would block. f is just a plain old file, so you when get to the end reads don't block, they just return nil instantly. As a result `select` returns instantly rather than waiting for something to be appending to the file as I assume you're expecting. Because of this you're sitting in a tight busy loop, so high cpu is to be expected.

If you are at eof (you could either check `f.eof?` or whether `gets` returns nil), then you could either start sleeping (perhaps with some sort of back off) or use something like [listen](https://github.com/guard/listen) to be notified of filesystem changes

Comment: You've correctly identified the busy problem, but your proposed solution is awkward.  He would be better off avoiding the temp file entirely and piping the output from the log tailer to a simple blocking read loop.  This will save storage and io overhead and make the desired blocking behavior on next line simple.

Comment: fairpoint - i didn't follow the link to the gist to be honest.